# What are the consequences of changing my Kindle's region?

Tags: kindle, amazon, drm

I used to live in the US, but now I live in Germany.  I own a lot of books on the US Amazon site.

I'd like to switch my Kindle to Germany so I can purchase books in German...but if I do, what happens to my US books?

The US site says this: [About Transferring Your Amazon Account to Another Website](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=2012488400)

> Transferring your account to your local Amazon website will transfer the digital content from the list below to the new account and allow you to purchase content from the Kindle Store in your local currency.
>
> May Transfer
> The following content will transfer to your new Amazon account, as long as the content is available for purchase from the new Amazon website.
>
> Kindle books
> *[and some other things are listed]*

But suppose I own a book on the US account that is *not* available for purchase on Amazon.de.  What happens to that book?

I gather it'll be unavailable on my account after the region switch.  But will it still be there if I switch back to the US?

Answer (score 0):

It may not show up in your library based on what they are saying. This is a publisher distribution licensing issue. But, you should still be able to log in to Amazon.com (ie US) and read it in the web reader, or on a different device.